# Celery: @shared_task and non-standard BROKER_URL

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery-task

I have a Celery 3.1.19 setup which uses a BROKER_URL including a virtual host.

```
# in settings.py
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/yard'
```

Celery starts normally, loads the tasks, and the tasks I define within the @app.task decorator work fine. I assume that my rabbitmq and celery configuration at this end are correct.

Tasks, I define with @shared_tasks and load with app.autodiscover_tasks are still loading correctly upon start. However, if I call the task the message ends up in the (still existing) amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/ virtual host.

**Question**: What am I missing here? Where do shared tasks get their actual configuration from.

**And here some more details**:

```
# celery_app.py

from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery('celery_app')
celery_app.config_from_object('settings')

celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(['connectors'])

@celery_app.task
def i_do_work():
    print 'this works'
```

And in connectors/tasks.py (with an `__init__.py` in the same folder):

```
# in connectors/tasks.py

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def I_do_not_work():
    print 'bummer'
```

And again the *shared* task gets also picked up by the Celery instance. It just lacks somehow the context to send messages to the right BROKER_URL.

Btw. why are shared_tasks so purely documented. Do they rely on some Django context? I am not using Django.

Or do I need additional parameters in my settings?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be limited to shared tasks. Just tasks in a separate file seem to behave the same. The question is rather where do tasks get there context from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The celery_app was not yet imported at application start. Within my project, I added following code to `__init__.py` at the same module level as my celery_app definition.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

try:
    from .celery_app import celery_app
except ImportError:
    # just in case someone develops application without 
    # celery running    
    pass
```

I was confused by the fact that Celery seems to come with a perfectly working default app. In this case a more interface like structure with a NotImplementedError might have been more helpful. Nevertheless, Celery is awesome.